# How to copy data inside BIGSQL table to .txt

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, bigsql

this might be very silly question but I am getting a hard time to figure out a way to copy data inside my `BIGSQL table` to a `.txt` in local file system.

Comment: Not sure what BigSQL is, but if you use hive you can do `hive -e "select * from table" > output.txt`. That will dump the output of the select statement to `output.txt`

Comment: Our organization is using BigInsights cluster, service provided by IBM and bigsql is just like hive, but faster than hive.

Comment: Ah, okay. Still, if you can use a CLI to query the table, you can direct the output to a file as I mentioned. A quick google search brought me to the [jqsh CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bsql_jsqsh.html).

Comment: `'select * from XYZ' > /tmp/pig_test/party.txt` didn't work
_Error: [State: 42601][Code: -104]: An unexpected token ""select * from XYZ" > /" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.67.33_

Comment: Well, you are missing a FROM between the * and table. Also, you have to run it from shell (bash, zsh, etc.), not the CLI.

Comment: then it says command not found. I rectified the missing `from`.

Comment: Okay. Going back to my initial hive example (I know you aren't using Hive). So from bash, I can do `hive -e "query"` where the hive **command** **e**valuates (with `-e`) the query string. The `>` character is an output redirection for bash, not part of hive. If I were to type `select * from table > output.txt` in Hive (or any SQL equivalent), it will throw an error because "> output.txt" is not recognized as a valid query string.

Comment: I tried diff combinations `jsqsh -D` , `jsqsh -A` based on the documentation... A stands for auto connect... D stands for database connection but none worked.

Comment: Alright. Ignore the "> output.txt" for now. How do you normally query the data?

Comment: same as any sql `select * from xyz;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the size of the resulting data file, you can use the *export* command to get the data into one text file.  **The resulting file will end up on one node**.

I used the following script as an example:

```
\connect bigsql
drop table if exists stack.issue2;

create hadoop table if not exists stack.issue2 (
f1 integer,
f2 integer,
f3 varchar(200),
f4 integer
)
stored as parquetfile;

insert into stack.issue2 (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (0,0,'Detroit',0);
insert into stack.issue2 (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (1,1,'Mt. Pleasant',1);
insert into stack.issue2 (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (2,2,'Marysville',2);
insert into stack.issue2 (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (3,3,'St. Clair',3);
insert into stack.issue2 (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (4,4,'Port Huron',4);

select * from stack.issue2;

{ call sysproc.admin_cmd('export to /tmp/t1.unl of del select * from stack.issue2') };

\quit
```

Running the script:

```
jsqsh --autoconnect --input-file=./t1.sql --output-file=t1.out
```

Yields:

```
cat t1.out
+----+----+--------------+----+
| F1 | F2 | F3           | F4 |
+----+----+--------------+----+
|  0 |  0 | Detroit      |  0 |
|  2 |  2 | Marysville   |  2 |
|  3 |  3 | St. Clair    |  3 |
|  1 |  1 | Mt. Pleasant |  1 |
|  4 |  4 | Port Huron   |  4 |
+----+----+--------------+----+
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| ROWS_EXPORTED | MSG_RETRIEVAL | MSG_REMOVAL |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
|             5 | [NULL]        | [NULL]      |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```

and the exported file:

```
ls -la /tmp/t1.unl
-rw-r--r-- 1 bigsql hadoop 93 Mar  3 16:05 /tmp/t1.unl

cat /tmp/t1.unl
0,0,"Detroit",0
3,3,"St. Clair",3
2,2,"Marysville",2
1,1,"Mt. Pleasant",1
4,4,"Port Huron",4
```

Answer (score 0):

Beauty of bigsql is you can connect just like you do a regular db2 database and call export.

```
[bigsql@myhost ~]$ db2 "create hadoop table test1 ( i int, i2 int , i3 int)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[bigsql@myhost ~]$ db2 "insert into test1 values (1,2,3), (4,5,6),(7,8,9),(0,1,2)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[bigsql@myhost ~]$ db2 "export to output.del of del select * from test1"
SQL3104N  The Export utility is beginning to export data to file "output.del".

SQL3105N  The Export utility has finished exporting "4" rows.


Number of rows exported: 4

[bigsql@myhost ~]$ cat output.del
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
0,1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to extract via SQL (as csv in this example) is as follow:

```
create hadoop table csv_tableName
  row format delimited fields terminated by ','
  location '/tmp/csv_tableName'
as select * from tableName
```

You can then get the file/s from HDFS.